# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'

Tags: vb.net, datarowview

I need to retrieve the "id" from datasource of the selected item, but it always throws the same error mentionned in the title. Here is my code

```
        Dim DMV As DataRowView = LbMCat.SelectedValue 'Here occurs the error
    SelectedMainCat = DMV.Item("id") 

    'Filling the SUB Categories part / same code used to fill Main categories
    Dim DataAdapterCats As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * From catS where maincat = '" & SelectedMainCat & "';", MySqlConnection)
    Dim dsSc As New DataSet
    DataAdapterCats.Fill(dsSc, "SubCategories")
    Dim SDataTable As DataTable = dsSc.Tables(0)
    LbSCat.DataSource = SDataTable
    LbSCat.DisplayMember = "title"
    LbSCat.ValueMember = "id"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below

```
Dim DMV As DataRowView = TryCast(LbMCat.SelectedItem, DataRowView)

If DMV IsNot Nothing Then
    SelectedMainCat = DMV.Item("id")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Direct Cast the value :

(DirectCast(LbmCat.SelectedItem, DataRowView)("ID").ToString())

[See it here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?724081-Unable-to-cast-object-of-type-System-Int32-to-type-System-Data-DataRowView). It may help

Comment: Same error, Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

Answer (score 0):

what if you check is the selected value is not integer??

```
If Not TypeOf (LbMCat.SelectedValue) Is Integer Then
    Dim DMV As DataRowView = LbMCat.SelectedValue 'Here occurs the error
    SelectedMainCat = DMV.Item("id")     
End If
```